# How to check if an event has fired?

Tags: c#, events, pushsharp

I have trouble with the implementation of my code. I'm currently using the PushSharp library and one of the things I'd like to do is if the event triggers, I would like to return a true or false value depending on what event it is. Here is the code:

```
public static bool SenddNotification()
{
var push = new PushBroker();

        //Wire up the events for all the services that the broker registers
        push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;

}


static bool DeviceSubscriptionChanged(object sender, string oldSubscriptionId, string newSubscriptionId, INotification notification)
    {
        //Currently this event will only ever happen for Android GCM
        Console.WriteLine("Device Registration Changed:  Old-> " + oldSubscriptionId + "  New-> " + newSubscriptionId + " -> " + notification);
        return false;
    }

    static bool NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + sender + " -> " + notification);
        return true;
    }
```

So what I'd like is if the event fires, return true or false depending on what happens, and then eventually return this value in the first method

Comment: So, is it an either or type of scenario, or will there be times both will fire?

Comment: there should not be an instance where both fire.

Comment: I'd say create a global bool, and return that in your events, then return it in your first method. But, it's not pretty.

Comment: to be honest I have no idea what that means, and I have no idea how to go about solving this :P so ... even if its not pretty ! Any help would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a global bool variable, and have your events set that variable, then have your first method return it. Something like this:

```
private bool globalBool;

public static bool SenddNotification()
{
var push = new PushBroker();

        //Wire up the events for all the services that the broker registers
        push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;

        return globalBool;  
}


static bool DeviceSubscriptionChanged(object sender, string oldSubscriptionId, string newSubscriptionId, INotification notification)
    {
        //Currently this event will only ever happen for Android GCM
        Console.WriteLine("Device Registration Changed:  Old-> " + oldSubscriptionId + "  New-> " + newSubscriptionId + " -> " + notification);
        globalBool = false;
    }

    static bool NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: " + sender + " -> " + notification);
        globalBool = true;
    }
```

Of course, you'll have to check it for `null` before you return it, and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Why would I have to check for null?

Comment: Oh nvm... if none of the events fire

Comment: @user2094139: Exactly. If no events fire, then it'll return null, and that could have undesired results.

Comment: So i ran into a few problems
1) The name doesnt exist in the context
2) it says that I have the wrong return type ..

Comment: @user2094139: What name?

Comment: globalBool doesnt exist in the context

Comment: @user2094139: Are they all part of the same class?